# How should I pass a lambda function as a parameter to another function in Android using Kotlin

Tags: lambda

I am trying to use a lambda method which will add two numbers and I am trying to pass that method as a parameter to another method. But I am unable to achieve this. Could anyone please help me out on this?

Not only Int, I also need understanding of how to use Strings here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s assume, you’re trying to add two integers and it is returning a result, which is also an integer of-course. 
In Kotlin, we can simply create a lambda function as the following:

`fun addTwoNumbers(): (Int, Int) -> Int = { first, second -> first + second }`

This means, the **addTwoNumbers()** will accept **2 Int parameters** and it will also **return an Int** type.

Let’s now break this down for better understanding:

**(Int, Int)** : this denotes the addTwoNumbers() will accept 2 Int parameters.

**-> (Int)** : this denotes the addTwoNumbers() will return an Int value as a result.

Also notice how we have used the parenthesis **{ }**.

This is how lambdas are defined and the functionality of that lambda is provided inside the parenthesis, like this :- **{ first, second -> first + second }**.

Now let’s create another method which will **accept lambda as a parameter**, like below:

```
fun sum(  
    x: Int,  
    y: Int,  
    action: (Int, Int) -> Int //Notice how we are passing the lambda as a parameter to sum() method. 
) = action(x, y)
```

This type of functions are also known as **Higher Order Functions**.

Now, we can simply use it like the following:-

```
fun main() {
    val summation = sum(10, 20, addTwoNumbers())
    println(summation)
}
```

This will print **30** in the console.

Comment: Thanks for this lovely informative answer!

Comment: If you've found it useful, could you please accept my answer? Cheers!

Comment: Oh sure! Cheers mate!

Comment: Can I do the same for Strings as well?

Comment: Oh yes, you can do these for Strings as well.

Comment: Could you please help me with a code snippet with Strings? I am just asking as I am pretty new to these things.

Comment: No worries buddy!

You can use String like the following:

Comment: fun sum(x: String, y: String, action: (String, String) -> String) = action(x, y)

Comment: In fact this action: (String, String) -> String) = action(x, y) could accept and return anything! It could be Double, Boolean or any type!

Comment: Now when you call it like the following:

Comment: fun main() {
    val summation = sum("Ten", "Twenty", addTwoNumbers())
    println(summation)
}

Comment: Output will be: TenTwenty

Comment: Thanks a ton for clarifying stuffs. It helped me a lot. :)

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: One more thing. This lambda function can take any number of parameters right?

Comment: Yes, it can take any number of parameters.

Comment: fun addThreeNumbers(): (Int, Int, Int) -> Int = { first, second, third -> first + second + third }

Comment: fun sum(
    x: Int,
    y: Int,
    z: Int,
    action: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
) = action(x, y, z)

Comment: fun main() {
    val summation = sum(10, 20, 30, addThreeNumbers())
    println(summation)
}

Comment: This will print : 60

Comment: Super useful. :)

Could you also please tell me how to return one lambda function from another function?

Comment: Oh! I am afraid I should say that here as the scope of this post is limited to "passing function as an argument". 

You can go ahead and create a separate question for "returning lambda from another function" and the StackOverflow community members will definitely help you out in this regard! Cheers!